# Alinhar o tamanho de acordo com o maior texto

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown, submenu

Tenho um menu e alguns submenus, preciso que o submenu fique alinhado o **width** dele de acordo com o texto maior, pois existe textos que podem conter apenas 5 palavras mas textos no submenu que podem conter 15, então precisa ficar alinhado de acordo com o 15 para não haver aquela quebra de linha. Tenho o seguinte `CSS`

```
nav > ul > li{display:inline;margin-left:57px;position:relative;}
nav > ul > li > a.active{color:#e6007e;border-bottom:3px #e6007e solid;padding-bottom:5px;}
nav > ul > li > a:hover{color:#e6007e;border-bottom:3px #e6007e solid;padding-bottom:5px;}
nav > ul > li > a{text-decoration: none;color:#a1a3a5;font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;}

nav > ul > li > ul{
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 23px;
padding: 4px 7px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.7s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.7s ease;
-moz-opacity: 0.00;
opacity: 0.00;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha"(Opacity=0);
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > ul{
visibility: visible;
text-align: left;
background: #e6007e;
color:#fff;
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
-moz-opacity: 1;
opacity: 1;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha"(Opacity=100);
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

nav > ul > li > ul > li > a{color:#fff;text-decoration:none;font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;}
nav > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover{text-decoration: underline;}

nav > ul > li > ul > li{
display: block;
font-size: 12px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Adicione também seu HTML na pergunta que fica mais fácil de te ajudar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta fazer o uso da propriedade `white-space: nowrap;` que impede quebras de linha a não ser que haja um `<br>` em seu código, pode ler mais a respeito neste artigo do Maujor [**aqui**](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/texttut.php).

Depois basta aplicar a propriedade `min-width` ao invés de `width` como você havia feito para não cortar o texto caso exceda o tamanho do elemento definido ficando `min-width: 200px;`.

Exemplo (Baseado na folha de estilo citada na pergunta, somente apliquei a organização de código da ferramenta do SOPT):

```css
nav > ul > li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 57px;
  position: relative;
}
nav > ul > li > a.active {
  color: #e6007e;
  border-bottom: 3px #e6007e solid;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
nav > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #e6007e;
  border-bottom: 3px #e6007e solid;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
nav > ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #a1a3a5;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}
nav > ul > li > ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 23px;
  padding: 4px 7px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  -moz-opacity: 0.00;
  opacity: 0.00;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha"(Opacity=0);
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: left;
  background: #e6007e;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha"(Opacity=100);
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  min-width: 200px; /* Para o texto não cortar o texto */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Para não haver quebra de linha */
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Lorem Sub Lorem Sub Lorem Sub Lorem Sub Lorem Sub Lorem Sub Lorem</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Lorem</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Lorem</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**OBS:** Apliquei comentários nos trechos onde apliquei as propriedades citadas para fácil visualização.